# OpenCV compiled with CUDA support usable without CUDA?

Tags: opencv, cuda, opencl

I've just compiled openCV (2.4.7) with Cuda and OpenCL support. Now we have another version (2.4.6) already in use, which was compiled **without** cuda and openCL support. I would like to replace the older binaries with the new ones.

Now I have the problem/question: Can I "deliver" the binaries (2.4.7) that were compiled with cuda support, without any problems instead of the old (2.4.6) binaries (that were compiled without cuda etc.), if I don't use any functionality from gpu or ocl? Or do they have any dependencies that could lead into problems?

Thank you for your help!

Mike

Comment: I think it should work, because the cuda and opencl support are in seperated OpenCV modules and libraries. If you don't need them, than just don't linke those in your project.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you must consider if the functions you are using in openCV lib in 2.4.6 are defined with the same way as in 2.4.7. I think this has to do with the backward compatibility and I think you are ok as far as this concept. Now If you are gone to use cuda build opencv maybe cudart.dll is probably needed. Maybe some other .ddl form the cuda sdk is also needed. According to my knowledge in the past I had to use opencvcore and opencvhighgui dlls (not gpu dll) and the cuda sdk dlls was needed.

I hope that helps, If I understand correctly you question.

**PS**: Sorry for the not exactly mentioned dll file names. I do not have access to the lib files for these days.